# SVN log commits from HEAD-n to HEAD-n+m?

Tags: svn

I'd like to see an `svn log` of up to `M` commits starting from `N` steps backwards from the HEAD.

Something like an SQL statement, if you like. Or a `-r N:M` range which supports simple arithmetic..

I'd like to avoid having to "grep" the actual integer corresponding to HEAD:

```
head_as_int=$(/usr/bin/svn info | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^Revision: (\d+)$/'
```

I suppose this would be ideal:

```
svn log -r HEAD-$n:HEAD-$n+$m
```

which is not supported. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `-l` flag?

```
svn log -l5
```

If you want a particular range of revisions, then you can do this:

```
svn log -r1345:1350
```

Of course, you can use Bash (or whatever shell you're in to do the arithmetic):

```
svn log -r$N:$((N+5))
```

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I was looking for. I still have to hack my way around getting a NUMBER for the current HEAD revision, though.. don't I?

Comment: @Robottinosino: Ah, I see.  You want it relative to head.  I'm not sure there's a neat way to achieve that.  I would probably write a helper script/alias that just extracts the current revision from a URL.  (e.g. `svn info | grep "Revision" | something something`).

Comment: `h=$(/usr/bin/svn info | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^Revision: (\d+)$/')` like this, basically..

Comment: @Robottinosino: You may find the `svnversion` utility of some use (but perhaps not much use, as it tells you the version of the working copy, not the repo itself).

Comment: Right... well it just sounded "reasonable" to be able to do `HEAD-3` or even `HEAD-1+5` but I guess I'd have to implement that if I really wanted it built-in! :)